# Appending words from a file to other different files

Tags: python

I have a text file in which the content is a conversation between different people.For ex-

```
WILL: Hii , 
ROYCE: Hello , 
WILL: How r u? , 
ROYCE: Fine , 
WILL: Where have h been?
```

I want to create a new text file for each of the characters with their name and store the unique words said by them in their respective file. How can I do this using python?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.For this we would have to create two separate files first.

```
with open('Will.txt', 'r+a') as newfile_1,open('Royce.txt', 'r+a') as newfile_2:
     Will_lines_lst = newfile_1.readlines()
     Royce_lines_lst = newfile_2.readlines()     
     with open('name_file.txt','r+w') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line not in Will_lines_lst and line[0] == 'W':
                 newfile_1.append(line)
            elif line not in Royce_lines_lst:
                 newfile_2.append(line)
```